# Correct way to write a stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, differential-equations

A few days ago, I disccussed my Phd thesis (thesis defense), one of the mathematical mistakes that the committe members alerted me to it, is how to write correctley an ordinary differential equation or a stochastic differential equation, they said to me that the correct way to write an ordinary differential equation is:

$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=f(x,t)$ and $dx(t)=f(x,t)dt$ is false, and for a stochastic differential equation the right way is $dx(t)=f(x,t)dt+LdB(t)$, $L$: is square root of the gain matrix of the process noise.

what is the rationale behind these two expression, because for example I saw in many times that the two expression are used for the deterministic models?

Comment: That seems incoherent - they use differential form for the SDE (which in fact is an integral equatiot), but not for the ODE? Is that correctly understood?

Comment: What is the symbol "$\partial$" in the ODE intended to mean?  That symbol is not generally used in accounts of ODEs.  You seem to use it in place of the differential operator $\mathrm{d}.$  Provided you supply the right definition, there's no mistake--but there's certainly potential for miscommunication.

Comment: Re the edit: if somebody tries to tell you $\mathrm{d}x(t) = f(x,t)\mathrm{d}t$ is "false" or nonsensical, then just refer them to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Tangent_vector_and_the_differential, which defines $\mathrm{d}t,$ for instance, as a linear functional on the tangent space $T_t\mathbb{R}^1.$